# DynamoDB CDC event ordering - Kinesis Data Streams vs DynamoDb streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-kinesis

Reading the documentation for DynamoDB cdc streams, there is a table which lays out some of the differences between using Kinesis Data Streams and DynamoDB streams. The "Ordering of records" row says the following for Data Streams:

```
The timestamp attribute on each stream record can be used to identify the actual order in which changes occurred in the DynamoDB table.
```

vs DynamoDB Streams:

```
For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item.
```

I interpret this wording as DynamoDB streams guaranteeing ordering based on item modification order in dynamo where as this isn't guaranteed for Data streams. Is my interpretation correct?

Currently I'm using Data Streams for CDC, but need to make a new app which requires that records are in based on when they were inserted into dynamo. Can I continue to use Data Streams or should I  enable DynamoDb streams as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I interpret this wording as DynamoDB streams guaranteeing ordering based on item modification order in dynamo where as this isn't guaranteed for Data streams. Is my interpretation correct?

That is correct understanding. Item level ordering, which means modifications to a single item will be guaranteed to be in order of when the occurred.

> Currently I'm using Data Streams for CDC, but need to make a new app which requires that records are in based on when they were inserted into dynamo. Can I continue to use Data Streams or should I enable DynamoDb streams as well?

I would use DynamoDB Streams as it streamlines having to maintain order across multiple shards of your stream.

---

| Properties | Kinesis Data Streams for DynamoDB | DynamoDB Streams |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data retention | Up to 1 year. | 24 hours. |
| Kinesis Client Library (KCL) support | Supports KCL versions 1.X and 2.X. | Supports KCL version 1.X. |
| Number of consumers | Up to 5 simultaneous consumers per shard, or up to 20 simultaneous consumers per shard with enhanced fan-out. | Up to 2 simultaneous consumers per shard. |
| Throughput quotas | Unlimited. | Subject to throughput quotas by DynamoDB table and AWS Region. |
| Record delivery model | Pull model over HTTP using GetRecords and with enhanced fan-out, Kinesis Data Streams pushes the records over HTTP/2 by using SubscribeToShard. | Pull model over HTTP using GetRecords. |
| Ordering of records | The timestamp attribute on each stream record can be used to identify the actual order in which changes occurred in the DynamoDB table. | For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item. |
| Duplicate records | Duplicate records might occasionally appear in the stream. | No duplicate records appear in the stream. |
| Stream processing options | Process stream records using AWS Lambda, Kinesis Data Analytics, Kinesis data firehose , or AWS Glue streaming ETL. | Process stream records using AWS Lambda or DynamoDB Streams Kinesis adapter. |
| Durability level | Availability zones to provide automatic failover without interruption. | Availability zones to provide automatic failover without interruption. |

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "it streamlines having to maintain order across multiple shards of your stream". The only order I really need to maintain is the order of items written to a given partition. Are you saying that this order isn't guaranteed and also a partition's items aren't guaranteed to be sent to the same shard?

Comment: Firstly you cannot control which items are in a given partition, just because they share the same partition key does not necessarily mean they will share the same physical partition (for example, if a single item collection > 10GB)......

Shards in KDS is defined by you, if you have 4 shards each one of those will have a Lambda consumer (assuming you're using Lambda) and its difficult to compare sequence numbers across multiple separate containers.

Comment: Yikes, okay. I was hoping that dynamo's cdc offered guaranteed ordering of item interactions (at least per partition key), but it looks like it doesn't. I'll have to come up with a different solution. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It's not guaranteed but for the most part will be ordered per partition.